# How To Delete A FileNode In An OpenCV FileStorage Object

Tags: opencv

I'm basically reading several fields in an OpenCV FileNode, doing some calculations, and then replacing just *one* of the fields in the original OpenCV FileNode with the calculated data.

I can't find any methods that allow me to do this. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, it appears that I cannot append or add to an existing filenode or filestorage object.

However, what you can do is create a new FileStorage object, copy over any existing FileNodes you may want to keep, discard any old fields you do not want, and then save this new FileStorage object with the updated data.

I couldn't find a way to use the latest C++ interface to copy FileNodes, however, I did find a way to use the old deprecated structures to accomplish this. The following will copy mapped FileNode to a new FileStorage object.

```
cv::FileStorage fileStructure;
fileStructure.open("yourfile.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

CvFileStorage* fsPtr= fileStructure.operator *(); //gets the underlying pointer

cvWriteFileNode(fsPtr, "CopiedNode", fileNodeObject.operator *(),0);
```

I hope this helps people who are stuck like I was.

Best,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV 4.0, there is a member function of [FileNode](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/de/dd9/classcv_1_1FileNode.html#a279bef7b343cbe935402be1d1ee8bdcf)

```
void setValue (int type, const void *value, int len=-1);
```

I haven't try, but it seems to design for this.

Answer (score 0):

There seems not to be any official way to do this prior OpenCV 4.x. A workaround is to use the underlying basic element:

```
//type int with value of 5
cv::FileNode node;
CvFileNode* rawNode = *node;
//now the new value is 6
rawNode->data.i = 6;
```